# Backup of a MySQL database on Amazon EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I back up my Amazon EC2 MySQL database?

I heard about Amazon Glacier, but I could not implement it.

Is there a simple and inexpensive alternative to this?

Answer (score 1):

If it a normal MySQL database. Use whatever technique you would normally use for MySQL.

Additionally, you could take a snapshot of the EBS volume, but be careful about consistency if you have multiple disks attached.

An alternative is to use Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) instead of running your own database on an EC2 instance. Amazon RDS has an in-built snapshot capability to automatically backup your database.

Answer (score 1):

SSH into your EC2 instance

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/<your-group-security>.pem ec2-user@<ec2-public-IP>`

Then run backup command

`mysqldump <db-name> > backup.sql`

Check file backup generated

`ls`

Then you can run below command to download it locally from EC2 instance

`sudo scp -i ~/.ssh/<your-group-security>.pem -r ec2-user@<ec2-public-IP>:/var/www/html/backup.sql ./`